# Validate document name inside an Alfresco folder

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I need some help regarding the script for Alfresco.

1. when I insert a document inside an alfresco folder it will be automatically renamed to another name. (this works) code below

```js
var nomeArquivo = document.name;
var novoNome = "";
if (nomeArquivo=="001.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CERTIDAO DE NASCIMENTO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="002.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "RG.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="003.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CPF.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="004.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CARTEIRA DE VASCINACAO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="005.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "PARECER DESCRITIVO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="006.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "RG DO RESPONSAVEL.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="007.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CPF DO RESPONSAVEL.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="008.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "COMPROVANTE DE RESIDENCIA.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="009.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "PASSAPORTE.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="010.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "REGISTRO NACIONAL DE ESTRANGEIRO - RNE.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="011.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CERTIDAO DE CASAMENTO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="012.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "TITULO DE ELEITOR.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="013.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "HISTORICO ESCOLAR DA GRADUACAO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="014.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DIPLOMA DA GRADUACAO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="015.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CURRICULO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="016.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CNH.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="017.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DECLARACAO DE DISPENSA RESERVISTA.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="018.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CERTIFICADO DE RESERVISTA.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="019.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "HISTORICO ESCOLAR.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="020.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CERTIFICADO DO ENSINO MEDIO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="021.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "HISTORICO ESCOLAR ENSINO MEDIO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="022.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "CERTIFICADO CONCLUSAO DO ENSINO MEDIO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="023.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DIPLOMA CONCLUSAO CURSO TECNICO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="024.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "ATESTADO DE VACINACAO (RUBEOLA OU TRIPLICE) PARA O SEXO FEMININO.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="025.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "BOLETIM DE DESEMPENHO NO ENEM.pdf";
  }  
if (nomeArquivo=="026.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DECLARACAO DE AUTORIZACAO DO COORDENADOR DO CURSO DE ORIGEM PARA CURSAR A DISCIPLINA NA FORMA ISOLADA.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="027.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "PLANO DE ENSINO DAS DISCIPLINAS CURSADAS (ENSINO SUPERIOR).pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="028.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DECLARACAO DE VINCULO E SITUACAO ACADEMICA REGULAR PARA TRANSFERENCIA.pdf";
  }
if (nomeArquivo=="029.pdf")
  {
    novoNome = "DECRETO OU PORTARIA DE AUTORIZACAO E OU RECONHECIMENTO DO CURSO DA INSTITUICAO DE ORIGEM.pdf";
  }
document.name = novoNome;
document.save();
```

2. I need to validate in the script itself if there is any document with the name that was renamed and I need this repeated document to be saved with the same name that is repeated, but it must be checked later. (you could add a code to this document)

PS.: I'm new to alfresco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Alfresco, you cannot duplicate documents name under the same folder.

Before save `novoNome` you have to check if it already has document with the same name, if it exist add a prefix or a suffix to it before save it  :

Here you can find example :

```js
var novoNome = getNovoNome(document.name);
//Get document foler 
var parent = document.parent;
// Check if a document with the same name exist;
var node = document.childByNamePath(novoNome);

if(node != null) {
    
    //Node with the same name already exist, you to set new name;
    //exemple we incrment number as prefix name until we find one that don't exist:
    var i=1;
    while(document.childByNamePath( i+"-"+novoNome)){
        i++;    
    };
    
    //Set New name with prefix to not duplicate existing names should be : i+"-"+novoNome;
    document.name = i+"-"+novoNome;
    document.save();
    
} else {
    
    document.name = novoNome;
    document.save();
}

function getNovoNome(nomeArquivo) {

    var novoNome;
    
    if (nomeArquivo=="001.pdf")
    {
        novoNome = "CERTIDAO DE NASCIMENTO.pdf";
        
    } else if (nomeArquivo=="002.pdf") {
                
        novoNome = "RG.pdf";
        //ADD all other conditions here
        // ...
        
    } else {
        //Finish with default case that return same name if none of the above condition is true 
        novoNome = nomeArquivo;
    }
    
    return novoNome;    
    
}
```